# Why does LindkedIn use hidden <code> tags in their (updated) website?

Tags: html, json, tags, web, linkedin-api

LinkedIn's DOM is full of hidden `<code>` tags filled with serialized JSON data.

These elements are not rendered anywhere on the page nor are used to represent a fragment of computer code.

Is there any performance benefit of doing this and what's the purpose of polluting the DOM with such data?

Comment: Because LinkedIn don't understand how to write quality HTML. There isn't a good reason to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that this speeds up rendering by removing dozes of AJAX calls.  Instead of performing many AJAX calls, the results of these calls can be pre-computed on the server, cached, and sent down with the initial page request without altering the architecture of the front-end site.  Certain ajax calls just have to scan the DOM for `$('code #datalet-something-something')` and if not found THEN proceed to use the network and talk to the server.

This is similar to hard-coding CSS styles above the fold to increase rendering speed.  Facebook does something similar with the BigPipe concept

https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/bigpipe-pipelining-web-pages-for-high-performance/389414033919

Now, why would you use <code> tags instead of <script> tags?  Because the browser pauses all rendering when it encounters a script tag.  Hiding data in code tags with display none causes no interruption to the rendering thread.

Why use code over div tags?  Why not?

Answer (score 0):

They use this tag to store application data, which they then use elsewhere from JavaScript. Example:

```
<code style="display: none" id="datalet-bpr-guid-1440862">
  {"request":"/voyager/api/configuration","status":200,"body":"bpr-guid-1440862"}
</code>
```

In itself there's nothing special about this, they could have used a div or any other tag really. I guess they've used `<code>` because it's indeed code, although that tag is usually used to display it not to include application data.

Comment: Why would you store responses from API calls and constants in the DOM?